# Showing value of Eloquent query containing column with object values

Tags: php, laravel, object, eloquent

I have a DB table with  column 'transaction'  contain object values.

In view file dd($receipts->transaction) is:-

```
"{"cancelled":"0","hash":"5a3ecdf73225d","order_id":"134","tx_date":"24-December-2017 00:43:45","tx_amt":"180.0000","Result":"CAPTURED","PaymentID":"3031646430073580","PostDate":"1224","TranID":"6582408430073580","Auth":"657402","Ref":"735800425124","tx_id":"1781","tx_mode":"KNET","tx_status":""}"
```

When i tried to print the tx_date -> {{$receipts->transaction->tx_date}}.

Giving error :
Trying to get property of non-object

I tried the following :

```
@php
$receipts->transaction = (object) $receipts->transaction;
@endphp
```

then 
{{$receipts->transaction->tx_date}}

Comment: Try with `json_decode($receipts->transaction)` before use of `{{ $receipts->transaction->tx_date }}`.

Comment: `$receipts->transaction` is not an object it seems its a json string you have to decode it first

Answer (score 0):

it happens because $receipts->transaction is an array, not an object.

instead of:

`$receipts->transaction->tx_date`

use:

`$receipts->transaction['tx_date']`